# The property "System.Windows.Forms.Control.Right" has not setter

Tags: c#, controls

I have a Button and I want to place it on right side of it's container (a panel).So I try to set button's Right property equal it's container's Left property. But this Error is showed :
The property `System.Windows.Forms.Control.Right` has not setter.

[This is a MSDN link :](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.right(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Did you read the link? `The Right property is read-only. You can change this property value indirectly by changing the value of the Left or Width properties or calling the SetBounds, SetBoundsCore, UpdateBounds, or SetClientSizeCore methods.`

Comment: Right is considered a derived value, so you need to change one or both of the constituents, ie Left (or X) and Width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Left` property of the control :

```
var panel = new Panel();
panel.Size = new Size(100, 100);

var button = new Button();
button.Size = new Size(20, 10);
button.Left = panel.Size.Width - button.Size.Width;
```

The reason why you can't set the `Right` is because it is computed from `Left` + `Width`.Here is diagram to help you understand :

[image]

Comment: I think I understood : Right property is equal by sum of its left container and it's width. Do i ?

Comment: @Majid Correct. In case you are interested here is the source for [`Control.Right.get`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,3637).

Answer (score 1):

Right property is Read-only and to change it I have to change Left property like this :

```
button.left=panel.right-button.width
```

And if my Form's state is Maximized , I have to write this code in Form_Load scope.